# Post problem in ASP.NET Framework with postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api, postman

Im trying to send some value with post to my ASP.NET Framework web API with Individual accounts.
However whenever i send something with postman object is set to null:
[image]

What can be a reason for that?

Comment: I found out that when i create binding model it works is there any way to post not using binding model?

Comment: If you just want to post a raw string value, then why are you posting JSON?

Comment: It is just a test post method. I'm trying to send whole object and it is also getting nulled. If i figure out how to send this string i'll be able to send whole objects. I've done it before, but after adding identity to my project it doesn't work

Comment: I know how to make it working for one field. But  show the real code, since this question is getting uselles already.

Comment: If you want to send a whole object, then why don't you want to use model binding?

Comment: I have generated classes from ado.net and wanted to use them

Comment: What do you mean you "generated classes from ADO.NET"? And what's preventing you from using them?

Comment: If i set received object as class it never works, the same situation is with string a it's value is always set to null. I am using ADO.NET Data Model and it is generating classes from database

Comment: Describe "doesn't work". What happens? What do your generated classes look like. In other words, you need to provide a [mcve] so we don't have to keep playing 21 questions with you.

Answer (score 0):

HI try to bind an object instead a simple string param .. something like:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] StringVM value) //<-- StringVM is a wrapper
{
 return Ok(value.Data);
{
```

And

```
public class StringVM{
 public string Data {get;set;}
}
```